# Place border around table except for first row

Tags: html, css

I want to have a table border that encompasses the entire table except for the first row.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: "The first row" - meaning the `thead`, or the first `tr` inside of the `tbody`? Could we see the markup and which row you want to exclude?

Comment: Thank you- you solved my dilemma with your comment. I separated the first row into the thead and placed the rest into the tbody. Then, I put a border around the tbody. If you rewrite your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a border around a `<tbody>` instead, and make the first row a `<thead>`? (Adding `thead`/`tbody` if necessary?)